# TextBox LostFocus infinite loop

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textbox in my form for user to key in an item code.
When the focus of the textbox is lost, it will look into the database to check if the item code exists or not.
However, I am getting infinite loop when I try to lose focus by clicking on other textboxes.

```
    private void txtICode_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtICode.IsFocused != true)
        {
            if (NewData)
            {
                if (txtICode.Text != null)
                {
                    if (txtICode.Text != "")
                    {
                        Item temp = new Item();
                        Item[] list = temp.Query(new object[] { Item.DataEnum.Item_Code }, new string[] { txtICode.Text });
                        if (list.Length > 0)
                        {
                            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("This item code is already being used.", "Invalid information");
                            txtICode.Focus();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The `txtICode.IsFocused` is set to true every time after the end of the method and the loop just continues forever.
I tried removing `txtICode.Focus();` but it makes no difference.
Is there anything wrong with my code?

I am using .Net 3.5 and WPF for my form.

Comment: why restore focus on `LostFocus` event?

Comment: Remove the msgbox & check!

Comment: Even after I comment out the messagebox, I am still getting infinite loop. I even comment out the `txtICode.Focus()` part.

Comment: where are you registering the LostFocus event, make sure you are subscribing to it multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to restore focus to `TextBox` in the LostFocus event.

remove these 2 lines :

```
txtICode.Focus();
return;
```

---

You could implement code more clean & readable way :

```
private void txtICode_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{        
    if (!NewData)
        return;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtICode.Text))
        return;

    Item temp = new Item();
    Item[] list = temp.Query(new object[] { Item.DataEnum.Item_Code }, new string[] { txtICode.Text });
    if (list.Length > 0)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("This item code is already being used.", "Invalid information");
    }
 }
```

Comment: This works good! Thank you! The codes were actually written by someone else, I am trying to fix some bugs and improve the codes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BeginInvoke Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc190259%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to execute asynchronously:

```
private void txtICode_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtICode.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
    if (txtICode.IsFocused != true)
    {
        if (NewData)
        {
            if (txtICode.Text != null)
            {
                if (txtICode.Text != "")
                {
                    Item temp = new Item();
                    Item[] list = temp.Query(new object[] { Item.DataEnum.Item_Code }, new string[] { txtICode.Text });
                    if (list.Length > 0)
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("This item code is already being used.", "Invalid information");
                        txtICode.Focus();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           private void txtICode_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
               string inputText = txtICode.Text;
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputText) || !NewData)
               {
                   return;
               }
               Item temp = new Item();
               Item[] list = temp.Query(new object[] { Item.DataEnum.Item_Code }, 
                                                       new string[] { inputText  });
               if (list != null && list.Length > 0)
               {
                  MessageBox.Show("This item code is already being used.", "Invalidinformation");
                  txtICode.Focus();
                  return;
                }
            }
```